# To Store attribute value in variable in piglatin

Tags: apache-pig

```
   %declare var relation2.$0;res = group relation1 by $var;dump res;
```

To Store first attribute of relation1 into variable var and then want to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store an entire column value in a variable and use it group it.It is incorrect.

[Source:%declare](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html):
Use to describe one parameter in terms of other parameters.

If you want group a relation by a certain column then use that column directly either by the column name or by the column index.Now if your aim is to only get records for a certain value then you would need to use a filter.

```
res = group relation1 by relation1.$0;
dump res;
```

Comment: Thank u , but the second relation has only one value in the tuple (i.e zipcode)and i want to use it to group first relation.

Comment: If it has one value why do you need to group it? You should always use column name for grouping and values for filtering.